# Execute a query then filter the results in memory or execute the exact query, which one is better and why?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume that there's a table Employee(Name, Age, Gender) and it has more than 10000 rows. I'd like to find out those employees whose name contains 'nick' and his age is between 18 and 24. I have two options to search the results. One is to execute a query to find out all employees whose name contains 'nick' and then do the filtering in memory. The other is to execute the exact query and get the final results. Which option is better and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With most performance questions, the answer is "run on your data and your system and see which is better."

In this case, though, the answer is obvious:  do the work in the database.  That is what databases are for.

Say you wanted to lend your bike to a friend who lives a couple miles away.  You could ride your bike over.  That is like doing the query in the database, because you are using the system in the way it was designed.  Or, you could walk your bike over.  That is like returning all the data to the application, incurring unnecessary overhead.

I could continue the bike analogy.  Just like a bike has gears to help with different terrain, a database has indexes and other structures to make queries run faster.  By not riding the bike, you are foregoing those advantages.

Comment: I'd say the second half of the analogy would be *Or you could take your bike apart, ship the pieces to your friend's house, walk over, and put it back together.*

Comment: yeah, splitting the gears and put them back together is more like what I'm doing now. And  dig into this question a bit more, say I have a basic query and return the collection of data which I used very often, and I use this collection by filtering it with different conditions quite often. In this case, is executing  a lot of the exact queries still better than executing a single query and filtering them? From other perspectives, like code complexity?

Comment: @user1657564 . . . That is a different set of trade-offs.  A powerful database can do the filtering using indexes, which could be a big win.  If the total amount of data you are returning from *all* the queries is substantially bigger than the size of the table, then storing the data locally might even make sense.  Imagine that you have to take that bike over sand . . . walking it might make sense under some circumstances.  It is just generally not advisable.